# Detecting text relevant to an entity in nlp

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, named-entity-extraction

I am trying to solve a problem where I'm identifying entities in articles (ex: names of cars), and trying to predict sentiment about each car within the article. For that, I need to extract the text relevant to each entity from within the article.

Currently, the approach I am using is as follows:

- If a sentence contains only 1 entity, tag the sentence as text for that entity
- If sentence has more than 1 entity, ignore it
- If sentence contains no entity, tag as a sentence for previously identified entity

However, this approach is not yielding accurate results, even if we assume that our sentiment classification is working.
Is there any method that the community may have come across that can solve this problem?

The approach fails for many cases and gives wrong results. For example if I am saying - 'Lets talk about the Honda Civic. The car was great, but failed in comparison to the Ford focus. The car also has good economy.'
Here, the program would pick up Ford Focus as the entity in last 2 sentences and tag those sentences for it.

I am using nltk for descriptive words tagging, and scikit-learn for classification (linear svm model).

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Is there some classifier I could build with custom features that can detect this type of text if I were to manually tag say - 50 articles and the text in them?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any help please??

Comment: Well what do you want is beyond common NER classification approaches. To recognize 'the car' as 'Honda Civic' (not in this particular sentence but in general) it is not enough to use previously recognized entity from previous sentence; you have to collect facts and build ontology that will recognize 'Honda Civic' as object of class 'car', and vocabulary-based recognizer should detect 'the car' as reference to 'car' ontology class.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. Any pointers or articles where I can construct such a text detector or classifier? Like a similar ontology example. The sentence could also say 'it', instead of 'car' - so it would be a little more exhaustive in that case. Should I use POS tagging and build an ontology classifier with a 'current entity' until the entity changes. Don't know how I should go about changing the entity as the new entity could or could not change the 'current entity' as in the given example.

Comment: @tzharg did you get any luck on this ?

Comment: Hey @Achyutanandasahoo sort of a direction that I'm going to try using deep learning. Attention-based LSTM neural nets for sentiment detection look promising if there is good enough training data. Ping me and I can send some recent papers that I found worth trying.